# how to hide that linear layout above soft keyboard in webview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

I have a question. I want hide the bar (the bar have two buttons: [prev], [next] in linearlayout) above soft keyboard in 'Glaxy Tab 10.1'. That is visible that only in webview.

How to hide a `linearlayout` above soft keyboard?

How to control a `linearlayout` above soft keyboard?

Comment: do u want to hide the soft keyboard am i right????